# Backbone fetch, promises and if else. how do they work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, promise

I have a problem that I'm not sure how to solve smartly in my backbone app. I have a view that requires either 2 or 3 different models to be fetched.

I have a profile view, that shows a customer his tasks and profile info, but when the coach accesses it, i also want to load the coaches model to enable the coach to switch stuff around.

How do promises behave with if else statements? Can I write the code in the way I have written and does it work that way?

```
var tasks = new App.Task.Collections.Tasks();
var coaches = new App.Coach.Collections.Coaches();
var user = new App.User.Models.User();

if(App.User.Models.currentUser.isCoach()){

    var userPromise = user.fetch();
    var coachPromise = coaches.fetch();
    var tasksPromise = tasks.fetch({
        data: {
            userId: userdId
        }
    });

    $.when(userPromise, coachPromise, tasksPromise).then(function(){

        App.Layout.page.show(layout);
    });

}else{

    var userPromise = user.fetch();
    var tasksPromise = tasks.fetch({
        data: {
                userId: userdId
        }
    });


    $.when(userPromise, tasksPromise).then(function(){

        App.Layout.page.show(layout);
    });
}
```

How do promises work with if else statements?

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks correct. The if/else statements in your code won't affect at all the promises because you have all the `.fetch()` calls in their corresponding blocks. Just remember to pass all those collections to the layout you are showing.

Answer (score 0):

you may collect your promises on an Array and then pass them to $.when

```
var promises = [];

promises.push( modelA.fetch() ); // default
if(value){ 
   promises.push( modelB.fetch() ); // conditionally added
}

$.when.apply($, promises).then(function(){
   // do your stuff
});
```